# When to put locks for multi-threading and multi-processing?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing

Do I need to do this while printing to standard output:

```
   `lock.acquire()`
    #printing to standard output
    lock.release()
```

For multi-threads and multi-processes.
Also does this has to be done while just reading from global file or value of a global variable??

PS: I am doing multi- threading and multi-processing in python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simplify to

```
with lock:
    print(something)
```

But yes, you need to avoid prints to be mixed by various threads.

When using readonly variables, you do not need a lock. When reading files (because you're changing state), you do need.

Comment: what about reading from global files or variables?? also do I do the same for multi-processing ??

Comment: What does changing state mean?? If differenet threads just use a global file for running an os command eg: running a command like,        python test.py <thread_name>_myoutput standard_output , here test.py just compares the two file character by character.test.py and standard_output are global files?? Also if threads read using different file pointers to a file ??

Comment: @sashasami That's not a problem. I though each thread would be reading parts of the same file...

Comment: @Jbernado what in the case of multi-processing ??

Comment: same thing. You only need locks when you change some state that is shared

Answer (score 0):

Python's print is thread safe due to GIL, you won't cause wreak to Python's internal state by printing from multiple threads.

However, if you want to make sure that multiple print statements will have all their prints grouped in logical manner, you do need a way to ensure that things are printed in the correct order. One way as you have discovered is to use lock, another IMO easier way is to build a single string that contains everything that needs to be printed together.

Comment: What about multi-processes ??

Comment: Print is not exactly thread safe (not even in CPython). If you print multiple arguments, it may interleave.

Comment: 'Python' doesn't have a GIL, only the cPython implementation does, so the first line doesn't apply to pypy, jython or ironpython...